# Multiple it statements with Jest and jasmine (nightmare.js)

Tags: jasmine, jestjs, nightmare

I'm using [nightmarejs](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#api) with [Jest w/async](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html#async-await)

This works fine:

```
describe('/ (Home Page)', () => {
  it('navigate /, then check title', async () => {
    await nm
      .goto('http://localhost:3000/')
      .wait(FIRST_LINK);

    const title = await nm
    .click(FIRST_LINK)
    .wait(FORM)
    .title()
    expect(title).toEqual('First link');
  });
});
```

But if I split into 2 `it()` blocks, like so:

```
describe('/ (Home Page)', async () => {
  it('navigate /', async () => {
    await nm
      .goto('http://localhost:3000/')
      .wait(FIRST_LINK);
  })
  it('check title', async () => {
    const title = await nm
    .click(FIRST_LINK)
    .wait(FORM)
    .title()
    expect(title).toEqual('First link');
  });
});
```

or like so:

```
  afterEach( (done) => {
    nm.end(done);
  });

  ...

  describe('/ (Home Page)', () => {
    it('navigate /', async (done) => {
      await nm
        .goto('http://localhost:3000/')
        .wait(FIRST_LINK);
      done()
    })
    it('check title', async (done) => {
      const title = await nm
      .click(FIRST_LINK)
      .wait(FORM)
      .title()
      expect(title).toEqual('First link');
      done()
    });
  });
```

Jasmine throws this error:

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

  at pTimeout (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:53:21)
  at Timeout.callback [as _onTimeout] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:523:19)
  at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
  at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
  at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
```

I'm a bit confused by this. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Hej Ashley, did you get this working?

Comment: Nope :( Looking at it now it seems like it just doesn't create a 'control flow' with async functions.  I'd probably try doing all the async stuff "between" the describe and it, then just use "it" calls after everything async had resolved.